# Spring Integration Java DSL Example

Tags: spring-integration

Could you please provide an example using spring integration java dsl for the following scenario:
On receipt of customer id by a topic consumer:

1. create a pojo CustomerInfo
2. call a rest service to get customer account info and set to CustomerInfo
3. call a rest service to get customer order info and set to CustomerInfo
4. Finally send CustomerInfo to a topic using claim check
   I used to work with xml config, java dsl is new to me.

I also wanted to check if Mark Fisher is publishing spring integration in action with java dsl.

Answer (score 1):

1. create a pojo CustomerInfo

Nothing more then `transform()` in Java DSL.

2. & 3. Perhaps you can use a `scatterGather()`. Or `enrich()` twice.
3. Not sure what does it mean "send using claim check", but probably it is like `claimCheckIn()` and then `handle()`.

Your use-case is not so straight forward to have as a general sample solution. Therefore unlikely there is a sample for your request.

All the info you needed for Java DSL you can find in Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl or just read JavaDocs on the `IntegrationFlowDefinition` methods to match them to required operator.